# 最大値を保存しつつ、リスト内の最小値と入れ替えたい

Tags: python

Python で遺伝的アルゴリズムのエリート保存をしたいのですが、`fitness` の中で最小値を取り出して、保存している `max_value` と入れ替えるにはどう書いたらいいでしょうか？

Python のリストで `fitness` というもので適応度を計算するのですが、その適応度の最大値を別で保存しておいて、次の世代の計算でそれよりも小さい最大値が出た場合に適応度の最大を入れ替えるということをしたいのです。

```
np.min(fitness).append(max_value)
```

これではだめですよね。

#### 追記

改めて自分で書いたコードではエラーが出ます。

```
if m_value < np.max(fitness): m_value=np.max(fitness)
if m_value > np.max(fitness): {fitness.remove(np.min(fitness))
                              fitness.append(max_value)
                         　　　}
```

次のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
fitness.append(max_value) 　 
　　 　^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

fitnessですが、`fitness = np.array(fit).astype(np.float)` です。
`fit=[]` となっています。変数の指定が悪いのでしょうか？

Comment: 本当にやりたいこととは別に、他の言語の知識が混入していて、まず表記が間違っているのでは？ `{ }`は他の多くの言語で複数の文を1つの文のようにまとめるものですが、Pythonではそういう使い方はありません。@nekketsuuu さん回答のように、次の行以後にインデントして記述するやり方に切り替えてください。

Comment: 申し訳ありませんでした。リターンを押すと編集が中断してしまうのでえいやっと入力してしまいました。以後気を付けます。

Answer (score 1):

[質問者さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/64063/19110)で `fitness.remove` ができるということは、`fitness` は NumPy Array ではなく Python の配列になっていそうです。ただ質問文的には NumPy Array とのことなので、NumPy Array の場合の回答を書きます。

わざわざ削除して挿入してを繰り返すのはやや無駄なので、代わりに代入で済ませます。また、`max` を何回も計算するのは無駄なので 1 回にします。

```
current_max = np.max(fitness)
if m_value < current_max
    m_value = current_max
else:
    fitness[np.argmin(fitness)] = current_max
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if m_value < np.max(fitness):
            m_value=np.max(fitness)

if m_value > np.max(fitness):
            fitness.remove(np.min(fitness)) 
            fitness.insert(0,m_value)
```

でいいと思います。｛｝は不要でした。